# BDD testing with cabybara: button not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara, bdd

I have a simple feature:

```
Feature: User can see the welcome page
Scenario: User can see the worker page
    Given I am on the welcome page  
    Then I should see the Worker button
    When I click on the  Worker button
    Then I should be on the Worker page

Scenario: User can see the requester page 
    Given I am on the welcome page  
    Then I should see the Requester button 
    When I click on the Requester button 
    Then I should be on the Requester page
```

What is strange is that I can pass the Then I should see the Worker button but cannot pass the click on test.

Here is my step definition

```
Then /^I should see the (.+) button$/ do |button_name|
  page.has_button? button_name
end

When /^I click on the (.*) button$/ do |button_name|
  #page.has_button? button_name
  click_on button_name
end
```

Here is my welcome page

```
  div.row
    %div.span6
      = button_to 'Worker', workers_path, :class => "btn btn-large btn-primary"
    %div.span6                   
      = button_to 'Requester', requesters_path, :class => "btn btn-large btn-primary"
```

Is the has_button? a method of Cabybara or Cucumber ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Then step will always pass regardless of what's on the page, since `has_button?` returns true or false, neither of which will cause your Cucumber step to fail.  For that to happen your step would have to throw an exception, which would best be achieved by using:

```
page.should have_button button_name
```

Answer (score 0):

has_button? is a method provided by Capybara.  It is documented [here](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Matchers#has_button?-instance_method)

Instead of `click_on button_name`  try `click_button button_name`